# development appengine (HRD) instance throws EOFException when loading from backing store (local_db.bin)

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

Since I have upgraded my GAE application to the HRD datastore, it does not work properly in my local development environment.
It is possible to import data into the local backing store, and local_db.bin clearly contains data (judging from its size).
Sometimes, I can then work with the local datastore.
But always when I restart the GAE server, the backing store cannot be read, and the following exception is thrown:

```
INFO: Local Datastore initialized: 
    Type: High Replication
    Storage: [path removed]\local_db.bin
[date time] com.google.appengine.api.datastore.dev.LocalDatastoreService load
INFO: Failed to load from the backing store, [path removed]\war\WEB-INF\appengine-generated\local_db.bin
java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readFully(ObjectInputStream.java:2699)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1935)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:479)
... more stacktrace lines ...
```

This occurs consistently. I am using App Engine SDK 1.7.4 and the Eclipse plugin. I am also using Objectify 3.1 for persistence.

There was a similar question on the old (now closed) Google groups forum, but no answer, which is why I post this here.

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening, and if there is a solution to this?

Comment: I started getting the same exception when I updated to 1.7.4 from 1.7.2. I am using master-slave db however.

Comment: Since a week or so, the problem has disappeared for me. For a reason unrelated to the problem described here, I increased heap space. In the debug configuration, under arguments / VM arguments, I added `-Xmx1024m`. It may be a happy coincidence, but since then the problem has gone away. However, I am not sure whether this answers my original quetion, since I did not see out-of-memory errors when that happened.

Comment: @enver it doesnt work for me even add -Xmx2048m. Did you find the solution?

Comment: @Daniel Robertus: After I increased the heap size, the problem has never returned. But as stated above, I am not sure whether this was the solution to the problem. Do you have exactly the same problem, described at the beginning of this thread? What is the version of your appengine SDK? How big is your local_db.bin? My local_db.bin file is 215MB. If yours is much bigger, memory might be the problem.

Comment: @enver at last i just remove my local local_db.bin file to somewhere else and just created new one and it solved. i upgraded my SDK from 1.7.3 to 1.7.6. And my local_db.bin is less than 5 KB.

Comment: @Daniel Robertus: I am glad the problem is solved for you. Perhaps the problem is also solved in 1.7.6, but in case it is not, for some people increasing heap-space might help.